# Cannot uncheck "Enable Just My Code" in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Every time I try to uncheck "Enable Just My Code" in Visual Studio 2008, the program hangs, and hence I can't uncheck it, which is a pre-requisite for me to use Reflector.

Has anyone else every had this problem? How do you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. This isn't an issue. It took upwards of ten minutes for the process of unchecking that box to complete. The first couple times I wasn't patient enough. Then, I unchecked it and went to lunch, came back and everything was fine.